# Remove indicator regimes that are less than three periods

Tags: r, loops, dummy-variable

I am looking for help with the following problem.

Suppose I have an indicator variable:

```
ind <- c(0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0)
```

My indicator variable is much longer so this is not a specific problem.

I am interested in writing a loop which does the following:

if the succession of 1's in the vector above is less than 3, keep it zero.

I.e. I want to remove frequent regime shifts where 1 is only 1 or two periods.

The final vector should thus look as follows:

```
ind <- c(0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

Any help in making this dynamic will be appreciated!

Nic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rle` to do this.  We get the `rle` of 'ind', change the 'values' by subsetting 'lengths' less than 3 for values that are 1 (`!!values`), assign the corresponding 'values' to 0, and use `inverse.rle` to convert back the output to `vector`.

```
inverse.rle(within.list(rle(ind), values[!!values][lengths[!!values]<3] <- 0))
#[1] 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Or a more compact version is

```
inverse.rle(within.list(rle(ind), values[values & lengths<3] <- 0))
# [1] 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: For code golfing, note that `!!x & y` is the same as `x & y` for numeric `x`.